# How to get orders items data from particular order?

Tags: orders, custom-options, magento2.3.1, items

I want to get details of custom options which selected whenever customer choose at order time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $options = $item->getProductOptions();        
    if (isset($options['options']) && !empty($options['options'])) {        
        foreach ($options['options'] as $option) {
            var_dump($option); //Look into the dump data for what you are looking for.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: welcome!! if it works :)

Comment: Yes, It is working.

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel accept the answer so it could help others.

Comment: Yes, I am new here. I accepted thanks.